# How can I generate some document site for my library project or multi-module project

Tags: android

I have some android project, which are multi-module, some of the modules are being published and used as library project, it has apis.

Need to generate some documentation site, which would have project description including module descriptions, build, integrations etc with some navigation panels, also need to link the javadoc into that site.

Something like https://github.com/realm/jazzy. Can you please suggest me some tools or ways here.

Answer (score 0):

To automatically generate documentation you need to add java [docs](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_documentation.htm) in you code, then in android studio `Tools -> Generate javadoc` there you configure for which of the modules you want the documentation.
This will generate docs similar to android developer site docs.

Comment: Thanks @Maksim Novikov, but I actually need to have some pages with project description including module descriptions, with java doc what it does, it arranges documentation with packages, in all of the modules. I need something like a Full project description page which will have link to each module page, in which build / integration instructions would be there and then I need to have java doc for public packages and classes in that.